# Unable to install mass storage devices

Tags: drivers, storage, usb-storage

For some reason, I am unable to install mass storage devices on my Windows 7 x64 machine. I see the error from the image below.

If I point directly at the `usbstor.inf` driver, I still get the error. If I copy the `usbstor.inf` and `.sys` files to another folder and point at it, I get a driver-not-signed warning, but the installation works correctly.

How do I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Look in Device manager, what is listed under Universal Serial Bus Controllers? Also run a SFC...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Comment: Have you tried more than one "mass storage device", or is it just one device you're having trouble with?  If it's just one, does it work in other computers?

Comment: @techie007 This is with all Mass Storage Devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, sometimes the file `usbstor.inf` disappears from the `C:\Windows\INF` directory. Manually putting it back fixes the problem.